# How to start a long-running thread in Python/Django

Tags: python, django, multithreading, schedule

I have a code which monitor cart,based on the user setting "how_often"(options are every 1,3 or 7 day).And I schedule it via [schedule](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

def startScheduleThread(how_often_setting, cart_id):

```
if how_often_setting==7:
    schedule.every().monday.do(monitor_cart, cart_id)
elif how_often_setting==3:
    schedule.every(3).days.at("10:30").do(monitor_cart, cart_id)
elif how_often_setting==1:
    schedule.every(1).day.do(monitor_cart, cart_id)
else:
    pass


while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(3600)
```

it's a long-running task, i decided to start a new thread(so main thread ain't blocked)

```
    how_often_setting = cart.how_often
    cart_id=cart.pk

    thread_obj = threading.Thread(target=startScheduleThread, args=[how_often_setting, cart_id])
    thread_obj.start()
```

the point is it works perfectly fine on a development server, but once i upload in on a real server - it does nothing.

Can anyone tell me why it's usually happening and how to even start such a long-running task. Thank you in advance

P.S. Please don't suggest Celery

Comment: why not celery?

Comment: Dont launch threads from a server process, use a distinct process for such tasks. Celery is the canonical solution here whether you like it or not, but there are other similar solutions like django-q (https://django-q.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) or huey (http://huey.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem on a django project. Its hosted on digital ocean. Like you i was starting a few threads, and it was running great on local host... but on production, it would not work.

The solution for me was to modify my server runtime command.

Below, I added the **--threads 7** flag and that solved it. Note I sometimes would create 30 threads and it would work fine (even though only 7 are specified in the runtime command).

```
gunicorn --threads 7 --worker-tmp-dir /dev/shm config.wsgi
```

I believe this will solve your immediate problem.